# bash: single quotes disappear while appending text to a file

Tags: bash, shell, echo, single-quotes, sshpass

I am trying to append a multiline text containing some single quotes(') to a file which is present on a different machine and can be only accessed through a different user.
Here is my code snippet:

```
element_list=("element1" "element2")
for element in ${element_list[@]} 
do

read -r -d '\n' CONTENT << EOM
field1 = on
field2 = '$element'
field3 = '$element-random-text'
EOM

    CONFIG_FILE=/tmp/config.txt
    sshpass -p vm_password ssh -t vm_user@<vm-ip> "sudo su - other_user -c 'echo \"$CONTENT\" >> $CONFIG_FILE'"

done
```

Though, the scripts execute successfully, the single quotes present in the field2 and field3 values disappear. The output appended to the file looks like:

```
field1 = on
field2 = element1
field3 = element1-random-text
field1 = on
field2 = element2
field3 = element2-random-text
```

I want those single quotes to dumped in the file too. Expected output:

```
field1 = on
field2 = 'element1'
field3 = 'element1-random-text'
field1 = on
field2 = 'element2'
field3 = 'element2-random-text'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: There is a requirement to execute this command from a different machine and using the other_user(not the vm_user).

Comment: The single quotes are matching the `'` before `echo`.

Comment: Mixing `ssh` and `sudo` commands like this is going to be tricky, because there are so many levels of quoting required, and they don't nest cleanly.

Comment: Right @Barmar, but this is the requirement. I cannot execute this script on the same machine and only the other_user can write to the CONFIG_FILE.

Comment: Do you have to do it with `echo`? Can't you copy the content as a file to the remote machine?

Comment: I have to append to an existing file present on the other machine. The existing file cannot be completely overritten.

Comment: I never said otherwise. `scp filename remote:/tmp/new; sudo other_user "cat /tmp/new >> $CONFIG_FILE"`

Comment: Learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net . If that doesn't fix it, then used updated code in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler solution is to perform all the expansion locally, and then just write the result at the end of the pipeline.

```
config_file=/tmp/config.txt
element_list=("element1" "element2")
for element in "${element_list[@]}"
do
    read -r -d '\n' content <<____EOM
field1 = on
field2 = '$element'
field3 = '$element-random-text'
____EOM
    echo "$content"
done |
sshpass -p vm_password ssh -t vm_user@<vm-ip> "sudo su - other_user -c \"cat >> '$config_file'\""
```

Capturing the here document only so you can then immediately `echo` it is obviously a waste of memory; I imagine your real loop body looks more involved.

Don't use upper case for your private variables; see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).
For robustness, I also added double quotes around `${element_list[@]}`; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. An additional change which was required was wrapping the command sudo su - other_user -c "cat >> '$config_file'" in double quotes. Final command looked like: 
sshpass -p vm_password ssh -t vm_user@<vm-ip> "sudo su - other_user -c \"cat >> '$config_file'\""

Comment: I removed unnecessary quotes around the `sudo su` command to simplify the command line. There are no shell metacharacters in the command so `ssh` will happily allow you to reduce the quoting.

Comment: I tried without quotes at first, but it gave this error:
`bash: /tmp/config.txt: Permission denied.`
Wrapping the entire command in double quotes fixes this though.
Maybe it is because I have used `ssh -t`

Comment: Ahhh I see, the `sudo` command needs to be separately quoted to prevent the remote shell from attempting to append to the file before getting privileges. I'll update the answer - thanks for the feedback!